# Using Pthreads on Xeon Phi Coprocessor

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, xeon-phi

I wrote a simple advection equation solver using pthreads which works correctly on the processor. However when I compile it using -mmic flag and run on coprocessor(using micnativeloadex), it uses just **one** thread(I am hard coding it to use 200). From what I know the code should work as it is. Am I missing something here?

The code is quite dirty, but still for completeness.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int64_t TimeInMicros() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec*1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
}


struct Grid{
  int nx;
  double *u, *u_new, *f, *res;
  double a, cfl, dx;
  double tf;
};


struct ThreadData{
  int tid;
  struct Grid *grid;
  int maxthreads;
  pthread_barrier_t *barr;
};

void *solver(void *args){
  struct ThreadData *td = (struct ThreadData *)args;
  int tid = td->tid;

  struct Grid *grid = td->grid;
  pthread_barrier_t *barr = td->barr;

  double *u = grid->u;
  double *u_new = grid->u_new;

  double cfl = grid->cfl;
  double a = grid->a;
  double dx = grid->dx;
  double tf = grid->tf;
  int nx = grid->nx;
  double *f = grid->f;
  double *res = grid->res;
  double dt = cfl*dx/a;
  double t = 0.0;
  int chunk = nx/(td->maxthreads);
  int start = tid*chunk;

  int rc;
  while(t < tf){
    // sync here


    if(start == 0){
    f[start+1:chunk] = a*u[start:chunk];
    }
    else{
      f[start:chunk+1] = a*u[start-1:chunk+1];
    }

    // sync here

    rc = pthread_barrier_wait(barr);
    if(rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)
    {
        printf("Could not wait on barrier\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    if(start == 0){
      f[start] = f[nx-1];
    }

    res[start:chunk] = -(f[start+1:chunk] - f[start:chunk])/dx;
    // need to use update u_new for multiple threads
    u[start:chunk] += res[start:chunk]*dt;

    rc = pthread_barrier_wait(barr);
    if(rc != 0 && rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)
    {
        printf("Could not wait on barrier\n");
        exit(-1);
    }



    t+=dt;
  }
  return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int nx=100000;//atoi(argv[1]);
  int nthreads=200;//atoi(argv[2]);

  if(nx%nthreads != 0){
    printf("ERROR: Number of cells should be integral multiple of number of threads \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  pthread_t *threads = new pthread_t[nthreads]();
  struct ThreadData td[nthreads];
  pthread_barrier_t barr;
  pthread_barrier_init(&barr, NULL, nthreads);

  double *u = new double[nx]();
  double *res = new double[nx]();
  double *f = new double[nx+1]();

  double dx = 1.0/nx;
  double cfl = 0.9;
  double a = 1.0;
  double tf = 1.0;
  int i;
  // initialize
  u[0:nx] = 0.0;
  u[nx/4:nx/2] = 1.0;
  f[0:nx+1] = 0.0;
  res[0:nx] = 0.0;
  struct Grid grid;
  grid.nx = nx;
  grid.a = a;
  grid.cfl = cfl;
  grid.dx = dx;
  grid.u = u;
  grid.u_new = u;
  grid.res = res;
  grid.f = f;
  grid.tf = tf;

  for(i=0;i<nthreads;i++){
    td[i].tid = i;
    td[i].grid = &grid;
    td[i].maxthreads = nthreads;
    td[i].barr = &barr;
  }




  int64_t t1 = TimeInMicros();

  for(i=0;i<nthreads;i++){
    pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,solver,&(td[i]));
  }

  for(i=0;i<nthreads;i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
  }

  int64_t t2 = TimeInMicros();
  printf("Execution time: %.10f\n", (t2-t1)*1e-6);

  FILE * outfile;
  outfile = fopen("results.txt", "w+");
  for(i = 0; i < nx; i++){
    fprintf(outfile, "%.10f %.10f\n", i*dx, grid.u[i]);
  }
  fclose(outfile);



  delete[] threads;
  delete[] u;
  delete[] res;
  delete[] f;



}
```

Comment: Well sorry for the premature post, it turns out the threads are correctly created however the processor usage remains as if they are not, might be because the threads are spending large amount of time waiting for the other threads.

Comment: I notice that you are using a barrier. This is never a wise thing to do in performance code. You might find this thread interesting: "Fastest possible barrier," https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/392587